# Virtual pageview sent to google analytics

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a page someone goes to when they are new with no website account. It's called the join page, so it's like a registration form page

We wanted to have a virtual pageview sent to google analytics when a user came from a specific page

But, this code won't work. Why won't this code work?

What is wrong with it?

here is the code

```
function gc_send_came_from_to_ga() {
    if (is_page('join') && is_user_logged_in() == true) {
        if(isset($_GET['from_page']) && $_GET['from_page'] !=""){
        $from_page = $_GET['from_page'];
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascrit">
            var from_page = '<?php echo $from_page; ?>';
            if(from_page == "home") {
                ga('send, 'pageview', "https://sampledomain.com");
            } else if(from_page == "childrens-ministry") {
                ga('send', 'pageview', "https://sampledomain.com/kids");
            }
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    }
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'gc_send_came_from_to_ga');
```

Comment: You have a syntax error on this line `ga('send, 'pageview', "https://sampledomain.com")`  That should be resulting in an error that you can see in your JavaScript console.

Comment: "Won't work" sounds pretty vague. What happens instead?